# Can I find whether the habit of people have changed using SPSS

Tags: spss

I am doing whether smoke affects on sleeping quality.

I have a set of data

1. whether people change of smoke since 1989:

1 = started, 2 = stopped, 0 = no change

2. whether people have difficulties of sleeping in 1985 and 1989

1 = yes, 0 = no

I would like to find out whether people change their smoking behaviour have an effect on sleeping quality by seeing the change of sleeping difficulties from 1985 to 1989. Is there any method to find out the change?

For example, make a new variables of whether the sleeping quality change
1 = yes(change from 1 to 0 in 1985 to 1989), 2 = yes (change from 0 to 1 in 1985 to 1989), 0 = no

Comment: welcome to Stack-Overflow! We'd like to help but the question you asked is not clear enough. If this is a programming (spss syntax) question, you need to edit your post and add some details about the structure of your data (a little sample would also help a lot) and what exactly you are trying to achieve. If this is a statistical question (so you're asking WHAT to do and not HOW) it is off topic here, and you should post it on [stack-exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As eli-k mentioned, your question isn't perfectly clear.  My understanding is 
that you 1) want to create a variable that categorizes change in sleep quality and 2) have variables `sleep_difficulty_85` and `sleep_difficulty_89` that indicate whether respondents had difficulty sleeping *(0=no; 1=yes)*.

```
COMPUTE sleep_quality_85t89 = sleep_difficulty_85 - sleep_difficulty_89 .
EXE .
VARIABLE LABELS sleep_quality_85t89 'Change in sleep quality from 1985 to 1989' .
VALUE LABELS sleep_quality_85t89
 -1 'worsened'
 0 'same'
 1 'improved' .
```

You can cross this variable with your `change_in_smoking` variable if you like.

```
CROSSTABS change_in_smoking BY sleep_quality_85t89 .
```